# Preventing reply-alls from Group MMS text messages?

Tags: iphone, sms

I have some family members with iPhones.  They have figured out how to send text messages to multiple recipients: start a new Message, and add multiple contacts in the To line.  Unfortunately, they have not figured out that replying to these replies to **everyone** who got the original text message.

Is there a setting that I can ask them to change on their phones to prevent these unintentional reply-all messages?  Or is there a way that I can tell my iPhone (4 on iOS 5.1) to ignore reply-alls?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the current version of iOS doesn't natively give us much control over something like that.

As I'm sure you are already aware of, it does allow us to turn off Group Messaging (and MMS *Settings* > *Messages*). However, that would defeat group texts in general - not just replies.

.....Maybe the next OS will?

Comment: I would have to imagine this is the #2 most requested http://www.apple.com/feedback/ right behind people wanting to be able to block phone calls on the iPhone. I hope everyone that wants these features is stuffing the ballot box with feedback...

Comment: You are probably right. I would love a feature like this as well as the ability to block calls.

Answer (score 2):

Select details next to the list of names, select the one name you want to reply to. This will bring up their contact information, select send message/text. Then select their cell number. This will start a new thread to just that person.

Comment: That's useful for me, but I want a way to prevent OTHERS from including me in a reply-to-all text.